# Error Verifying Request Signature - Next.JS 13 + Stripe

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to verify the request signature in my Stripe webhook endpoint and I keep getting error:

```
No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?
```

I've tried a multitude of solutions, multiple ways of parsing the raw request body. I've also tried manually verifying the HMAC sig. Nothing has worked.

My envinronment:

Next.js 13.3.2
Stripe SDK 12.4.0

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create an endpoint at: /pages/api/p/test

Code:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import safe from 'colors/safe';
import { buffer } from 'micro';

const handler = async (
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse
): Promise<void> => {
    const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET as string, {
        apiVersion: '2022-11-15',
    });

    const webhookSecret: string = "whsec_33244....";

    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'] as string;
        const buf = await buffer(req);
        const body = buf.toString();

        let event: Stripe.Event;

        try {
            console.log(safe.bgGreen(body))
            event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, sig, webhookSecret);
        } catch (err) {
            // On error, log and return the error message
            console.log(`❌ Error message: ${err.message}`);
            res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
            return;
        }

        // Successfully constructed event
        console.log('✅ Success:', event.id);

        // Cast event data to Stripe object
        if (event.type === 'payment_intent.succeeded') {
            const stripeObject: Stripe.PaymentIntent = event.data
                .object as Stripe.PaymentIntent;
            console.log(` PaymentIntent status: ${stripeObject.status}`);
        } else if (event.type === 'charge.succeeded') {
            const charge = event.data.object as Stripe.Charge;
            console.log(` Charge id: ${charge.id}`);
        } else {
            console.warn(`‍♀️ Unhandled event type: ${event.type}`);
        }

        // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
        res.json({ received: true });
    } else {
        res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
        res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
    }
};

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};

export default handler;
```

2. Start dev server and start a stripe listener

```
stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/api/p/test
```

3. Copy the webhook signing secret generated and paste in code
4. Initiate a simulated event

```
stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded
```

I've scoured the internet and tried everything. I'm totally stumped. I'm using `buffer` from microservices package but I've tried the buffer function in the example in Stripe's docs as well. It seems to be parsing the body correctly:

```
console.log(body)

{
  "id": "evt_3NIzhvEcQkKxoTiV1xjEMh02",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2022-11-15",
  "created": 1686772219,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "pi_3NIzhvEcQkKxoTiV1kuXEmH6",
      "object": "payment_intent",
      "amount": 2000,
      "amount_capturable": 0,
      "amount_details": {
        "tip": {
        }
      },
      "amount_received": 0,
      "application": null,
      "application_fee_amount": null,
      "automatic_payment_methods": null,
      "canceled_at": null,
      "cancellation_reason": null,
      "capture_method": "automatic",
      "client_secret": "pi_3NIzhvEcQkKxoTiV1kuXEmH6_secret_ZRnfaga3uRF5EhNXE0KwZpDpp",
      "confirmation_method": "automatic",
      "created": 1686772219,
      "currency": "usd",
      "customer": null,
      "description": "(created by Stripe CLI)",
      "invoice": null,
      "last_payment_error": null,
      "latest_charge": null,
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "next_action": null,
      "on_behalf_of": null,
      "payment_method": null,
      "payment_method_options": {
        "card": {
          "installments": null,
          "mandate_options": null,
          "network": null,
          "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
        }
      },
      "payment_method_types": [
        "card"
      ],
      "processing": null,
      "receipt_email": null,
      "review": null,
      "setup_future_usage": null,
      "shipping": {
        "address": {
          "city": "San Francisco",
          "country": "US",
          "line1": "510 Townsend St",
          "line2": null,
          "postal_code": "94103",
          "state": "CA"
        },
        "carrier": null,
        "name": "Jenny Rosen",
        "phone": null,
        "tracking_number": null
      },
      "source": null,
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
      "status": "requires_payment_method",
      "transfer_data": null,
      "transfer_group": null
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 2,
  "request": {
    "id": "req_MfPOwrw4MZsykJ",
    "idempotency_key": "10108c32-75db-4e1e-abb3-b3b2673df025"
  },
  "type": "payment_intent.created"
}
```

If anyone has ANY ides, I would be most grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had a character missing from the end of my test key.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Next.JS has middleware that manipulates the raw body of the request. Try turning off bodyParser for your route: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes#custom-config, otherwise you are going to need to make sure you get the raw request.

When you log the `body` in your endpoint before passing it to `constructEvent()` you should see a bunch of binary (which is what a buffer data type looks like). That is an indication you actually have the raw body. If you see JSON or a string then you know that the raw body has been manipulated and your Webhook signature verification will fail.

Comment: I have the config export in my code. It's at the bottom. I was suspicious about the output of body. It looks like formatted JSON. I agree it should be a bunch of jiberish. Any thoughts as to bypass Next body parse?

Answer (score 0):

You may have keys issue because stripe webhook have two keys one for localhost and second for production, you can grab this key go to developer, then webhook and then signing secret, [image]